# Shopware 6 - template not registered

Tags: shopware

I have been following [The developer training (SW6)](https://academy.shopware.com/courses/take/shopware-6-developer-training-english/lessons/).

It seems like the author skipped some important information.
My question is why `footer.html.twig`, footer was not visible in case of video but in my case it is displayed.

[image: Shopware]

Did anyone encounter the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things

- make sure your plugin is installed and active
- always make sure to clear the cash, e.g `psh cache` within the dev template, that's a common mistake to not clear the cache, while working with views
- you should extend from the [core twig file](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/master/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/layout/footer/footer.html.twig#L1) e.g

```
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/layout/footer/footer.html.twig' %}
    
{% block layout_footer_inner_container %}
   TEST
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher I uninstalled the plugin and then reinstall it. then it worked.